# hashing password using brcrpt in "pre"

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, mongoose

i am trying to store a hash of the password entered in a form using bcrypt in mongodb

this is the form

```
<form action="/register" method="POST">
<label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="fname" ></p><br/>
<label for="lastname">Lastname</label>
<input type="text" name="lastname" ></p><br/>
<label for="email">Email</label>
<input type="email" name="email" ></p><br/>
<label for="">Password</label>
<input type="password" name="password" ></p><br/>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
```

this is my mongoose schema

```
const userschema = new mongoose.Schema({   // define a schema  
    fname:{type:String,trim:true}, 
    lname:{type:String,trim:true},
    email:{type:String,lowercase:true,trim:true}, 
    pass:{type:String} 
});
```

and this is my pre function that is to be performed before save is called in my handler

```
userschema.pre('save',async function(next){
    const user=this;
    console.log(user);                  //in this log the user object this is containing plaintext value of password
    await bcrypt.hash(user.pass, 8, function(err, hash) {
        if(err){throw new Error(err);}
        else{
            user.pass=hash;
            console.log(user);          //and in this log the user object is containing hashed value as expected
        }
    })
    next()}
    );
```

and this is my handler for saving the user in the database

```
app.post("/register",function(req,res){
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        console.log(errors.array());
      return res.status(400).render("register",{ errors: errors.array() });
    }
    console.log(req.body);            //out of context question but for some reason only firstname and email are visible in req.body object can anybody body explain
    const usave=new user({
        fname:req.body.firstname,
        lname:req.body.lastname,
        email:req.body.email,
        pass:req.body.password
    })
    usave.save((err,doc)=>{
        if(err){res.send(err);}
        else{
            res.send("success");}
    });
});
```

when the route is handled the user is being saved succesfully but the password stored in the database is not being hashed.

I did make user.pass=hash in the schema.pre('save') function but its not being stored in the  database as hash just being stored as plain text

can anybody tell me what is wrong with this code?how do i save the hashpassword to database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
userschema.pre('save', async function(next) {
    var user = this;
    await bcrypt.hash(user.pass, 8, function(err, hash) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        user.pass = hash;
        next();
    })
});
```

The above code will accomplish your goal of always `hashing` the password when a document is saved to the `DB`, passwords are not hashed until the document is saved.

Comment: i dont think the salt is the problem as i metioned in the code comments the hashed password is visible in the user object when i console.log it but it is not being saved in the database as hash